# Chlamydomanas are present in Kingdom Protista or Plantae?

Tags: taxonomy, classification

*Chlamydomonas*, *Chlorella* are present in Kingdom Protista as well as  Plantae under division algae.

In which kingdom they correctly belong to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally accepted now that Chlorophyta are Plantae ([see here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21652308)). They are more closely related to plants than any other group of organism. Protist is a kind of basket term for any eukaryotic unicellular organism that is not an animal, fungi or a plant which is a rather exclusionary definition.

Personally, I think the kingdoms are pretty 'macro' oriented and do not really capture the diversity well of unicellular organisms. If you want to see a bunch of elderly scientist shout at each other over what appear to be arbitrary distinctions, I highly recommend attending the taxonomy session of any unicellular conference

Comment: What about Rhodophyta and Phaeophyta?? BTW Thnx;)

Comment: The rhodophyta might be monophyletic with the green lineage (have a common ancestor) but the Phaeophyta are definitely distinct and they likely arose during a seperate endosymbiosis event. They just do not fit in the five kingdoms. http://www.algaebase.org/ is quite respected for questions of algae taxonomy